# How to autofill data in google sheets based on values in a column

Tags: autofill

I have a column with a drop down list of the names of the students.
I want the other columns to read the name of the student written in the column from the drop down list and fill in the ID code of the student and the student address automatically.

I have a master sheet of all the students' names, IDs and addresses.

Comment: Did you try VLOOKUP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use VLOOKUP functionality of Google spreadsheet, if you are having master data in one sheet and you want to auto fill other based on Id or any field from your dropdown, VLOOKUP is the best solution Link : [See documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)